# Exercise 12:9.3. Bruckner's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, convex-geometry

The following is from Bruckner's *Real Analysis* :

[image]

In Exercise 12:9.3. :

Part (a) : If we want to make sure that $F(f)$ be common only on the value $1- \ln 2$ and because the lower bound of integration starts at $ \ln 2$ wouldn't that the minimum value for $a$ be $1$, no less?

Part (b) : If to consider $g=t - b$ then $a$ perhaps can be chosen less than $1$ but how the rigorous connection happens, I don't know?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\mathcal{C}[0,1]$. Let $h(t)=ae^t$ where $a\geq 0$.

Recall that $A=\{f \in X : \|f\|\leq 1\}$ and $B=\{f \in X : \|f-h\|\leq 1\}$.

**Item a**. Note that for all $f\in A$, we have $F(f)\leq 1 - \ln 2$. We also have that the constant function $1$ belongs to $A$ and $F(1)=1 - \ln 2$. So, $\sup \{F(f): f\in A\}= 1- \ln 2$.

So, in order that $F$ separates $A$ and $B$, we must have, for all $f \in B$, $F(f) \geq 1- \ln 2$. It is easy to see that this is true if and only if
$F(ae^t-1) \geq 1- \ln 2$. So,
\begin{align*}
 F(ae^t-1) & = \int_0^1(ae^t-1) dg =  \int_{\ln 2}^1(ae^t-1) dg = \\ 
 & =[ae^t-1]_{\ln 2}^1= (e-2)a-(1 -\ln 2) \geq 1- \ln 2
\end{align*}
So,
$$ a \geq \frac{2(1 -\ln 2)}{e-2}$$
So $F$ separates $A$ and $B$ if and only if $ a \geq \frac{2(1 -\ln 2)}{e-2}$. So, the smallest value of $a$ for which $F$ separates $A$ and $B$ is $ a = \frac{2(1 -\ln 2)}{e-2}$.

**item b**: It is easy to see that
\begin{align*} a > \frac{2}{e}  & \implies ae-1 >1 \implies \|ae^t-1\| >1 \implies \\  
& \implies \text{ there is a functional that separates $A$ and $B$. }   
\end{align*}

In fact, if $a > \frac{2}{e}$, we have $(\ln2 -\ln a) <1$. Define $g_a$ by $g_a(t)= 0$, if $0 \leq t \leq (\ln2 -\ln a)$  and   $g_a(t)= t-(\ln 2 - \ln a) $, if $ (\ln2 -\ln a) \leq t \leq 1$.  As in example 12.45, we define, for all $f \in X$,
$$ F_a(f)=\int_0^1 f dg_a$$
So, we have for all $f \in A$,
$$ F_a(f) \leq  \int_0^1 1 dg_a= \int_{\ln2 -\ln a}^1 1 dg_a = 1 -(\ln2 -\ln a)$$
Now, if $a > \frac{2}{e}$, we have $(\ln2 -\ln a) <1$ and we also have $ae^t-1 \geq 1$, for $(\ln2 -\ln a) \leq t \leq 1$. So, for all $f \in B$.
\begin{align*} F_a(f) & \geq  \int_0^1 (ae^t-1)dg_a=\int_{\ln2 -\ln a}^1 (ae^t-1) dg_a \geq \\
& \geq\int_{\ln2 -\ln a}^1 1 dg_a = 1 -(\ln2 -\ln a)
\end{align*}

Now note that is $a \leq \frac{2}{e}$, then $ae^t - 1 <1$ for all $t\in [0,1)$ and $ae^t - 1 \leq 1$ for $t=1$.
So,
$$A \cap B= \{f \in X : \forall  t, (ae^t - 1) \leq f(t) \leq 1 \} \ne \emptyset $$

Any functional $F$ that would separate $A$ and $B$ must assign the same value all $f \in A \cap B$. But any functional $F$ is of the form
$$ F(f)=\int_0^1 f dg$$
for some $g \in \text{NBV}[0,1]$.
So, since $ae^t - 1 <1$ for all $t\in [0,1)$ and $F$ must assign the same value all $f \in A \cap B$, we can easily conclude that $g(t)=0$ for all $t\in [0,1)$ (see **Remark** below). So $F$ is identically null and does not separate $A$ and $B$.

So we have shown that:

1. If $a > \frac{2}{e}$, there is a functional that separates $A$ and $B$.
2. If $a \leq \frac{2}{e}$, there is no functional that separates $A$ and $B$.

So, there is no smallest value of $a$ for which some linear functional separates $A$ and $B$. The infimum of the $a$ for which there are such linear functional is $\frac{2}{e}$.

**Item c**. If the question were asked for open balls, the answer for item b would not change.

In fact, if the question were asked for open balls, we would have
$A_1=\{f \in X : \|f\|<1\}$ and $B_1=\{f \in X : \|f-h\|< 1\}$. It is easy to see that a linear functional $F$ separates open balls $A_1$ and $B_1$ if and only if it separates the corresponding closed balls $A$ and $B$ (the closure of the open balls). So  the answer for item b would not change.

It is interesting to consider what happens for  $a=\frac{2}{e}$. In this case, $A_1 \cap B_1 =\emptyset$ (because if $f\in A_1$, then $f(1) <1$ and if $f\in B_1$, $f(1)> ae-1= 2-1=1$ ). We could then think that there is a functional that separates $A_1$ and $B_1$. However, there is no such functional, because, as said above, a linear functional $F$ separates open balls $A_1$ and $B_1$ if and only if it separates the corresponding closed balls $A$ and $B$ (the closure of the open balls).

$\square$

**Remark**: Let us prove in detail that if $F$ must assign the same value all $f \in A \cap B$, then $g(t)=0$ for all $t\in [0,1)$.

Note that, by Riesz Representation Theorem, $g \in \text{NBV}[0,1]$, so $g$ is a bounded variation function, $g$ is right continuous and $g(0)=0$.

Now, for a contradiction, suppose there is a $t_0 \in (0,1)]$ such that $g(t_0) \ne 0$. Without loss of generality, suppose  $g(t_0) > 0$. Since  $g$ is right continuous, there is $t_1 >t_0$ such that $g(t)>0$ for $t \in (t_0,t_1)$. Let $\varepsilon <\frac{t_1-t_0}{2}$ and let
$f_0 \in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ such that

1. $f_0(t) \in [0, 2-ae^{t_1} ]$, for all $t\in [0,1]$
2. $f_0(t) = 0$ for $t \in [0,t_0] \cup [t_1, 1]$
3. $f_0(t)=2-ae^{t_1}$ for $t\in [t_0+\varepsilon , t_1-\varepsilon]$

Clearly
$$F(f_0)= \int_0^1 f_0(t)dg > 0$$
But, it is easy to see that, for all $t \in [0, 1]$, $(ae^t - 1) \leq 1- f_0(t) \leq 1$. So, $1- f_0 \in A \cap B$. Since the constant function $1$ is also in $A\cap B$, we have
$F( 1- f_0(t))= F(1)$.
So,
$$ F(f_0)= F(1 - (1- f_0(t))) = F(1) - F( 1- f_0(t)) =0$$
Contradiction. So we have $g(t)=0$ for all $t\in [0,1)$.